# homebrew can't run my own formula

Tags: ruby, mongodb, formula, homebrew

I just follow the instruction to create my "own" homebrew formula from github, following this tutorial 
http://formalfriday.club/2015/01/05/creating-your-own-homebrew-tap-and-formula.html,
actually I just want to install mongodb older version, so I check the homebrew mongodb source code(because I like everything using homebrew, lazy guy uhuh...):

```
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb
```

I just want to change the Line 6:

```
 url "https://fastdl.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r3.0.1.tar.gz"
```

into:

```
 url "https://fastdl.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r3.0.0.tar.gz"
```

Nothing more, just version number, so I copy all the source cold, and create my own formula, but when I run the brew command, I got many errors including:

```
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 2: require: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 3: require: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 5: Formula: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 6: homepage: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 7: url: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 8: sha256: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 12: depends_on: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 13: go_resource: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 14: url: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 15: :tag: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 16: :revision: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 17: end: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 19: bottle: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 20: sha256: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 21: sha256: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 22: sha256: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 23: end: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 25: option: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 27: depends_on: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 28: depends_on: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 29: depends_on: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 30: depends_on: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 32: def: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 36: Language::Go.stage_deps: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 38: cd: src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 39: args: command not found
/usr/local/bin/mongold: line 134: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am fairly new to ruby and brew , thanks

Comment: The "require: command not found" means it's exercuting ruby in bash as if it were bash...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install it with `brew install ./mongo_old.rb` (the leading `./` is special); formulas are Ruby code and are not executable directly.

Comment: This syntax to manually install a file doesn't seem to work anymore in homebrew 1.3.1

Comment: Just used `brew install --verbose ./openssl.rb` successfully with `Homebrew 2.4.11-66-g24cb33b`

Comment: It still tries to fetch from the url written inside the formula. Is there a way I can avoid that and simply ask brew to install my formula from a directory ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 [Does this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017569/how-to-force-homebrew-to-install-a-local-file) help? Looks like you can overwrite the local cache file and it will install.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you sorted your issue. Adding this answer for future reference of the other readers;

[Formula-Cookbook](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook) is your friend. You may also refer https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/how-to-create-your-own-homebrew-package-or-formula-8dfbf8e001d3 for creating a new formula(disclaimer: I wrote it).

Try below simple steps;

- To create new formula; `brew create <URLOfTheDistribution>`
- Then debug it; `brew install --debug <NewFormula>`