# How to force homebrew to install a local file?

Tags: homebrew

I try to run:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

but got

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

because `http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/files/sshpass/1.06/sshpass-1.06.tar.gz` needs to be downloaded via a browser that runs JavaScript. Anyways now I have this file, and I put it in `$(brew --cache)` and run `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb` again but it is useless. Is there a command in homebrew to force install local tar.gz file or allow sshpass.rb to target a local file instead of an url?

Comment: I had no issue running your `brew install` command. `curl -L` works fine on the formula URL as well: https://gist.github.com/bfontaine/2699a7ea5ad5a39adaededacb0dda90b

Comment: @bfontaine it probably blocks direct download from certain IPs. Regardless, whether it can be downloaded is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple answer: you can’t; there’s no option to do that.

However you can override the cache download by yourself. Don’t use `$(brew --cache)`: it’s the general cache location, but Homebrew may use a different name for this formula’s cached download. To know the exact path use `brew --cache <formula>`:

```
brew --cache https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

Example output from my Linuxbrew install:

```
/home/me/.cache/Homebrew/downloads/b46bd79ca1d250486d5a0e0fcd455ed1d78eea689cf0612dffcdd7056b153efc--sshpass-1.06.tar.gz
```

Put your downloaded file **at this exact location**, with this exact name.

Homebrew will still try to make a `HEAD` request to the URL to check its `Last-Modified` header but won’t fail if that request doesn’t succeed.

Now run your command as before:

```
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
```

It should print something like "`Downloading https://…`" followed by `Already downloaded: …`.

Comment: Yes, but when you do that, the SHA256 SHA256 mismatch between expected and actual

Comment: @FalcoPeregrinus this question is about downloading the expected file by another mean. Since it’s the same file, there’s no SHA256 mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Also possible to download locally and run install from a local file:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kadwanev/bigboybrew/master/Library/Formula/sshpass.rb
brew install --formula ./sshpass.rb
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Run

```
brew install -b <formulae>
```

2. If a package fails to download, look for the cached location name and the url to download

```
Downloading https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.31.1.tar.xz

...

/Users/home/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/713e2ded9f716221e9b99f888e7c5e69b927b45d91be630596ea80c93ff5448e--git-2.31.1.tar.xz.
incomplete https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.31.1.tar.xz

curl: (35) SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect
```

Note 3 things from the response:

- Cache folder location: /Users/home/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/
- Cached file name: 713e2ded9f716221e9b99f888e7c5e69b927b45d91be630596ea80c93ff5448e--git-2.31.1.tar.xz
- Download url: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.31.1.tar.xz

3. Download the package by visiting the Download url
4. After downloading, change the name of the file to Cached file name exactly and put that file in the Cache folder location.
5. Run brew install again

```
brew install -b <formulae>
```

That did it for me! You might have to do these steps a couple of time if there are several packages you can't download with brew install